# MS Teams - Powershell / Scripting - Get-CsOnlineUser cmdlet delivers wrong output / PBX-Telephony

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

beeing a newbie in programming and powershell scripting, i hope that you can help me out with the following problem.

Currently iam working on a script to make it easy to assign a telephone-number to a AD-User. The idea is just to enter the name of the user and the script searches for the UPN and assigns the correct phonennumber to use in teams (pbx) . In the end the script should display the status of the team user to check if the number was configured correctly via **"Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity $aduserupn"**

The Script looks like this:

```
Write-Host  "Teams Script V1.4" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor DarkGreen


Connect-MicrosoftTeams
    
# Get user and store AD-Phonennumber

function step1 {
    $done = $False
    while (-not $done){    
        try
        {
            $aduser = $null
            $VoiceRoutingPolicy = 'Via-Provider-Policy'
            $decission = ''

            $user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the user.name'
            $aduser = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties telephonenumber -ErrorAction Stop
            $extension = $aduser.telephonenumber -replace '\s',''
            $aduserupn = $aduser.UserPrincipalName
         
            Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity $aduser.UserPrincipalName -PolicyName $VoiceRoutingPolicy -ErrorAction Stop
            Set-CsUser -Identity $aduser.UserPrincipalName -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true -HostedVoiceMail $false -OnPremLineURI tel:$extension -ErrorAction Stop
            write-host $aduser.UserPrincipalName
            Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity $aduserupn -ErrorAction Stop | select DisplayName, RegistrarPool, OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy, LineURI, OnPremLineURI, EnterpriseVoiceEnabled, HostedVoicemail         
            write-host "Done - Please check status above" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Green
            
            $decission = Read-Host -Prompt 'Do you want to activate another user? (y)es / (n)no'
            if ($decission -eq 'y'){
                
            } else {
                $done = $True
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            if ($aduser -eq $null) {
                Write-Host "The Username was not found, please try again!" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
            }
        }
    }
}

step1

write-host "Done - Disconnecting Session." -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Green
get-pssession | remove-pssession
```

The problem is, that this Get-CsOnlineUser cmdlet used with the script does not show me any result. When i directly enter it into powershell, it works and shows me the result:

```
DisplayName              : Name, Name
RegistrarPool            : sippoolAM41E07.infra.lync.com
OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy : Provider-Policy
LineURI                  : tel:+XXXXXXXXXXXXX
OnPremLineURI            : tel:+XXXXXXXXXXXXX
EnterpriseVoiceEnabled   : True
HostedVoiceMail          : False
```

All others csOnline-cmdlets are working fine. Do you see whats wrong here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `code` as a tag. That tag is just noise, it was deleted in the past and will be deleted very soon again.

Comment: Allright, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Copying answer from @panagiotis comments for better understanding.

DON'T use the script tag. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding code as a tag. That tag is just noise, it was deleted in the past and will be deleted very soon again.